# If-Then-ElseIf-Then In Mixed Integer Linear Programming

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, pulp

I'm trying to frame If-Then-Else-If... conditions in Python's PuLP.

I've looked at `If-Then` and `If-Then-Else` in MIP. 
However, I'm trying to understand how to propagate the choices further down to the next set of constraints and how to handle more than 2 decision branches.

To explain, consider the conditional constraints shown in the [image shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6VN0.png):

x and y are my decision variables. 
Basically, this reads as:

```
if x=0: C2>0 
elif x=1: C10>0
elif x=2: C3>0

if x=0 and y=0: 
    C4>0; 
    C8>0; 
    C10>0
elif x=0 and y=1: 
    C5>0; 
    C8>0; 
    C10>0
elif x=2 and y=0: 
    C6>0; 
    C9>0; 
    C10>0
elif x=2 and y=1: 
    C7>0; 
    C9>0; 
    C10>0
```

I know how to use the "Big M" technique for simple if-then-else situations. So for instance, if the problem was:

```
Problem: 
   if (x = 1) then (A < 0) else (B < 0)
Solution: 
   problem += A < M1*(1-x)
   problem += B < M2*x
```

What I don't understand is, how to change this for:

1. If there's more than 2 branches, so it's no longer a multiplication with x and (1-x).
2. If there are subsequent branches below the original decision, with more decisions that all depend on values from above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are really three steps involved here:

FIRST:

Reformulate the `x` variables so they are binary instead of in {0,1,2}. (Strictly speaking, this isn't necessary, but I think it makes the solution cleaner and easier to generalize.)

So, introduce three new binary variables `x0`, `x1`, `x2` and constrain them as follows:

```
x0 >= 1 - x
x0 <= 1 - 0.5x

x2 >= x - 1
x2 <= 0.5 x

x1 = x - 2x2
```

So: If `x = 0`, then the first two constraints require `x0 = 1`, the second two require `x2 = 0` and the last requires `x1 = 0`. And similarly if `x = 1` or `x = 2`. (You should double-check my logic.)

Your model will include your original `x` variables plus the new binary variables.

SECOND:

Create a new binary decision variable called, say `w_ijkl`, which equals 1 if `x0 = i`, `x1 = j`, `x2 = k`, and `y = l`, for `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` in {0,1}. Enforce this definition through the following constraints:

```
w_ijkl >= i*x0 + (1-i)*(1-x0) + j*x1 + (1-j)*(1-x1) +
          k*x2 + (1-k)*(1-x2) + l*y + (1-l)*(1-y) - 3
w_ijkl <= 0.25 * [i*x0 + (1-i)*(1-x0) + j*x1 + (1-j)*(1-x1) +
                  k*x2 + (1-k)*(1-x2) + l*y + (1-l)*(1-y)]
```

The first constraint says that if all four variables equal their targets (`i`, `j`, etc.) then `w_ijkl` must equal 1, and otherwise it can equal 0. The second constraint says that if all four equal their targets, then `w_ijkl` may equal 1, otherwise it must equal 0.

So, for example, w_0110 gets these constraints:

```
w_0110 >= 1-x0 + x1 + x2 + (1-y) - 3
w_0110 <= 0.25 * [1-x0 + x1 + x2 + (1-y)]
```

THIRD:

Use big-`M`s as desired to turn constraints on and off. So, for example, to require `C6 >= 0` if `x=2` and `y=0`, use:

```
C6 >= M * (w_0010 - 1)
```

(By the way, in general you can't use strict inequality constraints in a MIP -- you need greater-than-or-equal or less-than-or-equal constraints.)